# Use graphical modeler to loop through CSV columns

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3, for-loop

I'm looking for a way to loop through the columns of my CSV and implement this function that I made in the graphical modeler in QGIS.

[image]

I have two layers: (1) the map layer and (2) the delimited text (CSV) layer containing the coordinates and temperatures recorded by each station every 15 minutes.

[image: Graphical modeler function:]

I only know how to implement it manually for every feature in my CSV, but having a lot of features means it would be long and messy to do. Is there an easier way so that I wouldn't have to implement this manually in the graphical modeler for each feature in my CSV?